# Google pagespeed complaining about woff not being cached

Tags: nginx, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am currently optimizing the configurations of nginx pagespeed (ngx_pagespeed), and the pagespeed keeps complaining about the lack of caching woff files.

This is how my configuration looks like:

```
server {
    location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
    location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
    location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon" { }
    location /ngx_pagespeed_statistics { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
    location /ngx_pagespeed_global_statistics { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
    location /ngx_pagespeed_message { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
    location /pagespeed_console { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }

    pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
    pagespeed EnableFilters inline_google_font_css;

    access_log      /var/www/servers/mysite/production/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/servers/mysite/production/logs/nginx_error.log;
    listen          80;
    server_name     mysite.com;
    charset         utf-8;

    client_max_body_size    75M;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/var/www/servers/mysite/production/sockets/mysite.sock;
        include     /var/www/servers/mysite/production/configs/uwsgi/uwsgi_params_pro;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex   on;
        alias       /var/www/servers/mysite/production/static;
    }

    location /media {
        autoindex   on;
        alias       /var/www/servers/mysite/production/media;
    }
}
```

Do i need to define more parameters for my `/static` library that contains the `woff` files?

**UPDATE**

I altered my static location to detect if its the specific files that i wanted Cache-Control on and then added the parameters as following:

```
location /static {
    autoindex   off;
    alias       /var/www/servers/mysite/production/static;

    if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)|(svg)|(otf)$){
       expires 1y;
       add_header Cache-Control public;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngx_pagespeed does not currently support extending the cache lifetime for woff files. You could tell Nginx to serve woff files with a long TTL or request this feature from ngx_/mod_pagespeed.

Comment: How do i mix the `long TTL` with my current setup?

Comment: I don't know nginx very well, but `location ~* \.woff$ {
  expires 1y;
}` should work.